# Error fetching OAuth2 access token : 500 Error

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am being randomly bugged by the following error message:
This occurs when [php library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) tries to obtain the [access token](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php) line 112.

Sometimes my code obtains access token in first try, sometimes I need to refresh the URL containing 'code' as get parameter multiple times before access token is obtained.

This error is coming frequently for last 3-4 days.

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 
'<HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Error processing OAuth 2 request</TITLE> </HEAD> 
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> 
<H1>Error processing OAuth 2 request</H1> 
<H2>Error 500</H2> 
</BODY> </HTML> 
'' in /google-api-php-client-0.5.0/google-api-php-client/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php:105
 Stack trace: #0 /google-api-php-client-0.5.0/google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php(138): apiOAuth2->authenticate(Array) 
#1 l.php(191): apiClient->authenticate() 
#2 l.php(99): googoauthinit(true) 
#3 {main} thrown in /google-api-php-client-0.5.0/google-api-php-client/src/auth/apiOAuth2.php on line 105
```

The code I use is directly lifted from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/userinfo/index.php) (EXACTLY same code with all parameters like app name, secret key, id etc correctly filled).
Also, tried registering new app but same error is received.

Comment: See if this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396426/google-contacts-data-api-giving-500-error?rq=1

Comment: nope.. I tried registering new app with fresh client id, secret key etc but received same error.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a Google synchronization issue. Check out this [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/MHH8LqxBSXI) and see if you have a similar issue.

Comment: wow!! very interesting link. Don't tell me 'G'oogle cannot fix this issue. I cannot modify /etc/hosts on shared server nor do I want to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is similar to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428180/google-analytics-api-v3-http-error-unable-to-connect-on-live-server-localhos) on SO. You'll find the solution in the comments of the answer.

> To disable at run time, you can use
>   $this->client->setClassConfig("Google_Http_Request", "disable_gzip",
>   true) as well.

This worked great for me.