# Google Analytics API V3 - HTTP Error: Unable to connect on live server (localhost works fine)

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, file-get-contents, zlib, google-api-php-client

(I am using the latest version of this library: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

In short, my script works perfectly on localhost, but whenever I upload to our production or staging environments it fails.

I am now using a really simple test script from this tutorial: http://blog.salteh.net/2012/10/google-analytics-api-and-service-accounts/

Again, this works perfectly on localhost, but errors on our production and staging servers.

The error is:

```
HTTP Error: Unable to connect
```

From our error log, we get:

```
2014-01-29 10:14:43  /classes/google-api-php-client-read-only/src/Google/IO/Stream.php  115 php_error   {"error_message":"file_get_contents(compress.zlib:\/\/https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/o\/oauth2\/token): failed to open stream: operation failed"}   php_error
```

I believe this must be due to either file_get_contents() not working correctly or an error with the zlib compression.

I've therefore created a simple script to test (https://gist.github.com/jonmilsom/7771566cf55e042b4826) but this works fine on both localhost AND the staging & production environments.... how can I debug this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug further you can go to the API client library at /src/Google/IO/Stream.php and look for the line that is

```
throw new Google_IO_Exception("HTTP Error: Unable to connect");
```

You can append messages on to that... like this to get the http error code

```
throw new Google_IO_Exception("HTTP Error: Unable to connect " . $this->getHttpResponseCode($http_response_header));
```

Let me know if you come up with any solution, you may want to follow this issue: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/75.  My code works fine on my localhost, but not on my dev server as well but I have not figured out a solution.  I got Cloud Storage working by removing the gzip CONST at the top of the Stream.php, but Drive still does not work and I am thinking this all has to be related.

EDIT: Take a look at the issue I linked, basically you should try to set gzip to disabled in the Config.php - this fixed the issues for me.

I found this issue had to do with differing PHP versions between my localhost and my server

I submitted a new issue here:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/78

Comment: To disable at run time, you can use $this->client->setClassConfig("Google_Http_Request", "disable_gzip", true) as well.

Comment: Thanks @loomtronic & Ian Barber, I wasted alot of time on this... using Ian's neat solution in production now. Thanks

Comment: Now cURL is supported, so just in case you haven't checked out the latest version of the API client - you might want to do so.

Comment: Thanks Ian Barber! cUrl is supported now, but not on Google App Engine. So that setting for disable_gzip worked great for me.